# How to set labeled major ticks for every value of the axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It just so happens that my x axis is a datetime Series, but I imagine it would work the same with everything else.

I am aware that I could just set the ticks to some values (which gets tricky if you have dates, as it doesn't directly accept Series), but I imagine there must be a function that sets major ticks for all the values on the x axis. I thought that the following line would do it:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

and it does indeed create major ticks for all my values, but it just doesn't label some of them. I thought they were hidden, so I:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
```

But actually the labels of some of the ticks are just set to an empty string. If I don't use the above 2 lines, the automagic ticking creates somewhat more ticks, and all my values are actually labeled correctly.

Is there a way, apart from manually setting the ticks to some custom values, to tell matplotlib to tick and label each available value on the x axis?

I feel that this is trivial, but I'm fighting with it for a while, so here I am. Is there an easy way to tell matplotlib to

Comment: are you sure its not minor ticks that are not being labelled? Perhaps a [MCVE] would be helpful here

Comment: @tmdavison are you suggesting that the above lines should have done the trick and there's something else that changes the behaviour?

Comment: `MultipleLocator(1)` should put a labelled major tick on every integer value on the x axis. Beyond that, it's hard to say whats happening without seeing your code.

Comment: @tmdavison , but this is very good information, as it explains why the code above doesn't work. I thought 1 means 1 unit, with the unit being the difference between any adjacent values in the dataset (very wrong assumption on my side, as not all datasets are regular), but I see it refers to each integer value. This explains very well the behavior. I want to keep the question generic though. How to set major ticks for each value on the axis, without manually setting them, if this is even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "for each value on the axis"? Do you mean for each value in the data Series?

Comment: Say the x coordinates are ```np.random.rand(3)```, I want a tick for each of these 3 values. Preferably, not by setting the ticks to be at the exact same values, but by flipping a switch somewhere that all values to be plotted should also be major ticks.

Comment: Then I think you probably want a [`FixedLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator), but you still need to feed that the values being plotted. I'm not aware of any other way